# 1 a women's stereotype 2 a woman's stereotype 3 women's stereotype 4 a woman stereotype - what's the difference?

Tags: possessives

> 1 a women's stereotype
>
> 2 a woman's stereotype
>
> 3 women's stereotype
>
> 4 a woman stereotype

What do they mean?

My take

1 a stereotype which women have about something

2 a stereotype which women have about something

3 don't know

4 a stereotype of someone about women

Do you agree?

Comment: The 4 options in the title don't match the 4 options in the question body. Also, you should indicate what research you've already done on this issue; knowing whether you're familiar with the use of indefinite articles, attributive nouns, etc. could help people to provide better answers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question - your 4 options in the title is different from the ones in the body.

Comment: Ok, the "your 4 options in the title is different from the ones in the body" issue is solved. But you still need to tell us what research you've done on this issue (if you have done any), and tell us which part you still don't understand.

Comment: I have provided my understanding of the sentences. Is it correct or wrong?